# IPFSAccessController.save ERROR: Error: Deprecated, use .toString()

Tags: javascript, npm, ipfs, orbitdb

i'm only trying to launch the exemple of the app kit OrbitDB which is :

```
import OrbitDB from "orbit-db";
import IPFS from "ipfs";

async function main () {
  // Create IPFS instance
  const ipfsOptions = { repo : './ipfs', }
  const ipfs = await IPFS.create(ipfsOptions)

  // Create OrbitDB instance
  const orbitdb = await OrbitDB.createInstance(ipfs)

  // Create database instance
  const db = await orbitdb.keyvalue('ipfs_db')
}

main()
```

you can find it here : https://github.com/dappkit/aviondb#using-nodejs

but the problem is when i launch it, i got these errors :

```
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWM7D9NdMhtxyiWiKH4XVpuZW5oDu9MbWxFmEzLsG9UynM
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.1.53/tcp/4002/p2p/12D3KooWM7D9NdMhtxyiWiKH4XVpuZW5oDu9MbWxFmEzLsG9UynM
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4003/ws/p2p/12D3KooWM7D9NdMhtxyiWiKH4XVpuZW5oDu9MbWxFmEzLsG9UynM
IPFSAccessController.save ERROR: Error: Deprecated, use .toString()
    at CID.get toBaseEncodedString [as toBaseEncodedString] (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/multiformats/cjs/src/cid.js:94:11)
    at Object.writeCbor [as write] (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/aviondb/node_modules/orbit-db-access-controllers/node_modules/orbit-db-io/index.js:62:14)
    at async IPFSAccessController.save (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/aviondb/node_modules/orbit-db-access-controllers/src/ipfs-access-controller.js:46:13)
    at async Function.create (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/aviondb/node_modules/orbit-db-access-controllers/src/access-controllers.js:68:20)
    at async OrbitDB._determineAddress (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/aviondb/node_modules/orbit-db/src/OrbitDB.js:331:37)
(node:8397) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: `undefined` is not supported by the IPLD Data Model and cannot be encoded
    at undefinedEncoder (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/@ipld/dag-cbor/cjs/index.js:47:9)
    at objectToTokens (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/cborg/cjs/lib/encode.js:175:20)
    at Object (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/cborg/cjs/lib/encode.js:149:9)
    at objectToTokens (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/cborg/cjs/lib/encode.js:184:10)
    at Object (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/cborg/cjs/lib/encode.js:149:9)
    at objectToTokens (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/cborg/cjs/lib/encode.js:184:10)
    at encodeCustom (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/cborg/cjs/lib/encode.js:214:18)
    at Object.encode (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/cborg/cjs/lib/encode.js:236:10)
    at Object.encode (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/@ipld/dag-cbor/cjs/index.js:85:41)
    at put (/home/zar/Etna4/SmartContract/db_ipfs/node_modules/ipfs-core/src/components/dag/put.js:35:25)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8397) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:8397) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i seriously don't know what to do, i tried to clear the cache, to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, and do a `npm install`, but nothing changed, i got the same error, do you have any idea to fix this ?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue today, please let us know if you find the answer.

Comment: I will haha ! @DanielWhite

Comment: What is the version of js-ipfs that you are using right now?

Comment: Here it is : `ipfs --version :
ipfs version 0.9.1`

Comment: I meant the js-ipfs version that you have installed through npm. You can find it in `package.json`

Comment: And the request you asked : `jsipfs --version :
0.58.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error clearly points to an incompatibility between IPFS and OrbitDB.

The latest version of `js-ipfs` that OrbitDB v0.26.1 supports is `0.55.4`.
You should change the `ipfs` (or `ipfs-core`) version in your `package.json` to `^0.55.4`.

---

Note: [The upcoming OrbitDB v0.27, will support the latest IPFS version](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/issues/913).